# Javascript object definition undefined error

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript, but trying to make an object.  As far as I can tell document.gibado.Subway.Finals listed as undefined, but I don't understand why?  Can someone explain this to me?

The error I'm getting says that

> Cannot read property 'EMAIL' of undefined

This code doesn't work:

```
document.gibado.Subway = {
    Finals: {
        EMAIL: 'email',
        STORE_NUMBER: 'storeNumber',
        HIDE_OPTIONS: 'hideOptions'
    },

    hardQs: [{
        text: 'To what email address should we send your unique code?',
        answer: document.gibado.Subway.Finals.EMAIL
    }]
};
```

This code does work:

```
document.gibado.Subway = {
    Finals: {
        EMAIL: 'email',
        STORE_NUMBER: 'storeNumber',
        HIDE_OPTIONS: 'hideOptions'
    }
};

document.gibado.Subway.hardQs = [{
        text: 'To what email address should we send your unique code?',
        answer: document.gibado.Subway.Finals.EMAIL
}];
```

Comment: You can't refer to the object while you're defining it. It doesn't exist yet at that point.

Comment: The variable `document.gibado.Subway` isn't assigned until the statement completes, but you're try to access it before it's done.

Comment: I've also tried `answer: this.Finals.EMAIL` rather than `answer: document.gibado.Subway.Finals.EMAIL` and it still won't work.  Why is it still considered undefined at that point?

Comment: Again, you can't refer to something that doesn't exist, not even with `this`.